# Suggested edit rejected and edited with a more trivial edit

Tags: support

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172808/how-do-i-change-the-position-of-this-sliding-text-area) specifcally, I've suggested an edit three times now to improve the formatting. The first time it was rejected as the OP made a subsequent edit adding additional information to the bottom of the post. The second time it was [rejected and and edited by the reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8025307) with the explanation 'This edit did not correct critical issues with the post' when the reviewer's edit did not improve the formatting and instead corrected grammar. I was able to understand the grammar and answer the question correctly without questioning the grammar of the question.

Is a little bit of bad grammar seriously a critical issue that is more important than a badly formatted code section?

At what point should formatting of code take precedence over grammar and vice versa?

Why would the "improved edit" not improve the formatting?

Comment: The code *wasn't* formatted badly.  It was properly formatted as code.

Comment: It was formatted as code, but badly formatted as code, hence "Improved formatting" instead of "Corrected formatting"

Comment: It was formatted perfectly fine as code in a readable and appropriate manor.  You changed it to a different, but equally valid, presentation of that code.  You didn't "fix" anything.  You just changed it from a style that you don't like to one that you do.

Comment: That is not formatting, it is common for new users to copy and paste, find out that they need 4 spaces to make it a code block and because they are too lazy to indent every line with 4 new spaces, they will just indent the lines which arent indented enough.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the code was perfectly readable and formatted as code even before your edit.

Comment: The question was perfectly readable before the grammar was changed. That doesn't mean that it shouldn't have been changed to be made more readable. The same goes for the code. I'm not questioning whether the grammar edit was a valuable edit or not, I'm questioning whether or not a couple trivial grammar errors are a reason to reject the improved formatting. If the reviewer wanted to fix the trivial grammar, shouldn't he have included the improved formatting

Comment: He felt that your adding wasn't adding sufficient value to merit its suggestion.

Comment: The edit was approved by subsequent reviewers and this kind of edit is routinely approved every day. Why was it only reviewed by one person? usually I see three reviewers. Why was his reject and edit not reviewed by another reviewer?

Comment: Any reviewer can edit a post under review, approving or rejecting the suggested edit in the process.  That reviewers are constantly approving edits of little to no value is certainly not something that I would dispute, that doesn't mean it's a good thing, or that it's good reviewing.

Comment: Properly indenting code improves readability just as much as the trivial grammar change.

Comment: Of course, you were asking a bunch of people to take time out of their day to review your edit, make sure it's appropriate, not spend that time reviewing other edits, lock the post from other edits during that time, etc. None of which is true of the other user's edit.  Also, looking at both edits, I'd certainly say that his edit improved the readability of the post notably more than yours did.  You changed something from just fine to also just fine, he removed content that didn't need to be there and changed some of the structures in ways that have noticeable impacts on how the content is read

Comment: _"Is a little bit of bad grammar seriously a critical issue that is more important than a badly formatted code section?"_ It depends. In this case, the grammar was definitely more important as the code formatting _was not incorrect._ I see people use a very similar indention style all the time- It's the way they do things, good for them. With such a small amount of code, it did not impact readability much if any. _Grammar,_ however, can make a question harder to understand, especially for non-native speakers. Fixing up the grammar can be important for future viewers.

Comment: Basically- If the grammar is absolutely horrible, that's top priority. If the code is not in code blocks, that's over any other fixes, tied with the absolutely horrible grammar. If the code is in code blocks and you just don't agree with the indention or think that it should be in a snippet, fine, but at that point, grammar is pretty much above the code formatting as the code is pretty well formatted already.

Comment: Hey there. I'm pretty amazed I actually was the reviewer in cause, sorry that you felt unjustly left out here, but for the records, I rejected and edited because all I seen from what you did was move the code at the top while leaving the introductory paragraph as it was: a hard to read wall of text.

Comment: I was wrong. I just didn't understand why the improved formatting was left behind.

Comment: In all honesty, it's because I, as mentioned in other comments, did not feel it was an *improvement*. That being said, I do feel the issue has been explained thoroughly and wish you a great journey on SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might well have made the same decision as the reviewer. Switching from separate code blocks to Stack Snippet is a fairly trivial change: it's not bad, and I would have at least considered doing it myself, but it's not that big a deal either. Fixing indentation is even more trivial: again, I would have considered it, but there wasn't really anything wrong; you weren't, admittedly, simply pushing your own braces-on-same-line, tabs-not-spaces preferences or the like, but it wasn't unreadable the way it was.

Fixing grammar and question flow so you can actually read it cleanly before trying to dig into the code is, in my book, substantially more important. Whether I would have specifically chosen Reject and Edit (to get the point across that hey, there are bigger things out there) or Improve Edit (to just sigh and work with what's there) is a bit of a toss-up.

(Disclaimer: most good reviewers are at least somewhat jaded toward Stack Snippets because of how often they are misused to "format code" that is not HTML/CSS/JS in the first place. So, subjectively, that starts your edit off on the wrong foot.)

In comments you asked why the Reject and Edit decision was unilateral. The reason is partly technical and partly UX: SE software makes no real attempt to merge conflicting edits like a full version-control system, so if an edit goes through, it cancels all suggestions that hadn't yet settled in. And having reviewers vote on whether another 2ker's edit is acceptable doesn't make a lot of sense: at that privilege level, one is assumed to be competent at editing for the most part.

Comment: If the code will function properly when put into a snippet stack and will better portray the intent of the question so that the user answering the question doesn't in turn have to copy and paste the code into a jsFiddle to see the current output, is it not a relevant edit to do so?

Comment: I understand that they can be used improperly, but shouldnt the proper use of them be encouraged?

Comment: If you have an edit that improves a post by +0.1, and there's issues that could be fixed for +2.5, I'm usually going to Reject & Edit and do both of those for +2.6; if it's +0.5 and +1.25, I might hit Improve Edit instead. I'm not going to hit Accept. It's not about whether the edit is correct: it's about priorities.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: For reference, I take a different approach to Nathan.  I tend to approve minor edits unless they miss more-of-the-same kinds of issues.  Even then I will sometimes jump in and fix those myself.  Some reviewers miss the old "too minor" rejection reason, I personally don't.